# MySQLGeneral error 1005 при построении модели в symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mysql

Модель следущая:

```
KladrState:
  options:
    type: MyISAM
    collate: utf8_general_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    code_state: { type: string(3), notnull: true, unique: true, default: '000' }
    name: { type: string(40), notnull: true, unique: true }
    socr: { type: string(10), notnull: true }
    code: { type: string(13), notnull: true, unique: true }
    zipcode: { type: string(6), notnull: true }
KladrLocality:
  options:
    type: MyISAM
    collate: utf8_general_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    state_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    code_city: { type: string(3), notnull: true, default: '000' }
    code_locality: { type: string(3), notnull: true, default: '000' }
    name: { type: string(40), notnull: true }
    socr: { type: string(10), notnull: true }
    code: { type: string(13), notnull: true, unique: true }
    zipcode: { type: string(6) }
  relations:
    KladrState: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: state_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: KladrLocalities }

KladrStreet:
  options:
    type: MyISAM
    collate: utf8_general_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    locality_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    code_street: { type: string(4), notnull: true, default: '0000' }
    name: { type: string(40), notnull: true }
    socr: { type: string(10), notnull: true }
    code: { type: string(17), notnull: true, unique: true }
    zipcode: { type: string(6), notnull: true }
  relations:
    KladrLocality: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: locality_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: KladrStreets }
Compania:
  columns:
    name:      { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    product:   { type: string(255), notnull: true}
    address_id: { type: integer, notnull: true}
    sfera_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true}
    okved_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true}
    gruppa_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true}
    kladr_id:   { type: integer, notnull: true}
  relations:
    KladrStreet: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: kladr_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Comp}
    Okved:   { onDelete: CASCADE, local: okved_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: companias1 }  
    Sfera:   { onDelete: CASCADE, local: sfera_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: companias2 }  
    Grup :   { onDelete: CASCADE, local: gruppa_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: companias3 }  
    Address: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: address_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: companias4 }
```

При построении модели MySQL ругается на связь compania_kladr_id и Kladr_street_id.
Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам

```
options:
  type: MyISAM
  collate: utf8_general_ci
  charset: utf8
```

надо добавлять в начало описания таблицы